# File Explorer folders become unresponsive in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, files-folders

When I'm working on something, I usually have 3-4 Windows File Explorer folders open at the same time, minimized down. I then hover on the File Explorer icon on the Taskbar at bottom which shows the mini-display of the open folders, and I can then click on a folder to maximize it and bring it into full view.

After doing this for a few minutes, and without any discernible pattern, some or all of the folders begin freezing. I can hover and see the mini-display but clicking on the folder does nothing --- as if it had become unresponsive. I then have to re-open File Explorer fully, navigate to the folder, and start a new instance of it. Sometimes this happens in minutes, sometimes in an hour. I've had this experience on multiple laptops and I've come to accept it as part of the Windows experience.

Now I had enough. There must an explanation for this crap and I'm certain I'm not the only one. I can't believe Microsoft wouldn't have noticed this. Can anyone explain why this is happening and how I can get rid of it?

Clearing the File Explorer cache or disabling the preview pane etc does nothing. I also run Windows with minimal effects, no heavy background images etc, and the files in my folders are text files. I have top-spec laptop with 16GB RAM. This isn't a performance issue.

Comment: What file Explorer cache are you clearing? Are any of these files you're accessing on network drives? What is your specific computer model and what is the hard drive model?

Comment: No consolation to you, but I have a similar problem.  It appears to be due to intensive file opening/closing.  I am still looking for solutions.  maybe its explorer, or maybe its another application that perhaps doesn't behave.

Comment: Also, it is very doubtful this is due to a bug on Microsoft's part. I have loads or file Explorer windows open regularly, far more than 3 or 4, and they do not freeze as you describe. This is a problem with your computer, which is good because if it was MS fault we really couldn't do anything to suggest a fix for you.

Comment: @music2myear There's an option to clear the folder cache in Folder Options > General > Privacy. Accessing local files only. Laptop is Samsung Galaxy Book Pro, i7 (11th gen), 16 GB RAM, standard Samsung hard drives. I don't think there's any hard drive operation involved in this.

Comment: @RohitGupta Agreed, although it's nowhere near intensive enough that this should be happening.

Comment: There is an option to launch Explorer in a separate process for each window... or not. Which do you use, and why not state that in the question? https://winaero.com/how-to-start-file-explorer-in-a-separate-process-in-windows-10/

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I'm not really sure what that means. Each open folder is an instance of File Explorer. I use it just normally... Click, open folder, expect it to work like a folder until I close it.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Tried the separate process solution as per your link, doesn't solve the issue unfortunately.

Comment: I have seen this before.  Try a Windows 10 Repair Install, Keep Everything and hope for the best.  .......   https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10    ....  Second link, and run the file to Repair.

Comment: @John Thanks - I've had this on three different laptops. If that wasn't the case, I'd give it a try but I don't think a re-install will solve it.

Comment: Repair Install is not a Windows reinstall.  You can do a Repair and land where you left off. It does not always solve this issue but worth a try

Comment: @John Got it, thanks. Ok will take a look.